I need help finding a sneaky bug, tkinter python3 script
Buttons on the 2nd tab are way too spaced apart for some reason ive been trying to fix this for a decent chunk of time with random things like rowconfigure and frames etc but it never works.
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import webbrowser
import time
import os

# Creating all the functions of the program

def Open_Discord():
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
    
def biosite():
    webbrowser.open(url2,new=new)
    
def mygithub():
    webbrowser.open(url3, new=new)
    
def taskmgr():
    time.sleep(0.3)
    os.system("start taskmgr")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Multi Tool", message="Task Manager is Running!")
    
def ctrlpanel():
    time.sleep(0.3)
    os.system("start control")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Multi Tool", message="Control Panel is Running")
    

# Main settings of gui(title, size etc)
root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap('C:/users/eac/Pictures/multitool.ico')
root.title("Multi Tool")
root.geometry("500x400")

# Choosing wether to open new tab or window then setting the actual url to goto
new = 1
url = "https://discord.gg/dbApbadrwD"
url2 = "https://fakecrime.bio/eac"
url3 = "https://github.com/BigDawgStepper"

# Creating main notebook
my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
my_notebook.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

# Adding the tabs to the notebook/packing them
my_tab1 = ttk.Frame(my_notebook)
my_notebook.add(my_tab1, text="Welcome")
my_tab2 = ttk.Frame(my_notebook)
my_notebook.add(my_tab2, text="Tools")

# Tab 1 Labels
Label(my_tab1, text= "Welcome to BigDawgSteppers MultiTool", font= ('Helvetica 18 bold underline')).grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(my_tab1, text= "This Multi Tool has many features! Refer to the tabs at the top to locate tools!").grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(my_tab1, text= "Interested in my work or want to talk to me? Join the discord below!").grid(row=2, column=0)
Label(my_tab1, text= "You can join my disc using the button or copying this link! https://discord.gg/dbApbadrwD").grid(row=3, column=0)
Label(my_tab1, text= "Tool currently working for Win11 & Win10", font= ('Helvetica 18 bold')).grid(row=12, column=0)
Label(my_tab1, text= "Who is TheBigDawgStepper? Click the button below for more info...").grid(row=5, column=0)
Label(my_tab1, text= "This isnt the only tool ive made theres multiple version of this and more on my github!").grid(row=7, column=0)
Label(my_tab1, text= "^^^^AS OF 2024-05-22^^^^", font= ('Helvetica 18 bold')).grid(row=13, column=0)

# Tab 2 Labels
Label(my_tab2, text="Hey there this is the Tools Tab, have fun!", font= ('Helvetica 18 bold underline')).grid(row=0, column=0)

# Creating Frames
Frame(my_tab2, width=250, height=250).grid()

# Tab 1 Buttons
Button(my_tab1, text="Join my Discord Server Here!", padx=10, pady=10, command=Open_Discord).grid(row=8, column=0)
Button(my_tab1, text="Who even is TheBigDawgStepper?", padx=10, pady=10, command=biosite).grid(row=9, column=0)
Button(my_tab1, text="My github!", padx=10, pady=10, command=mygithub).grid(row=10, column=0)

# Tab 2 buttons
Button(my_tab2, text="Open Task Manager", command=taskmgr).grid(row=1, column=0)
Button(my_tab2, text="Open Control Panel", command=ctrlpanel).grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()

Ive tried to use rowconfigure to set the size but it didnt do anything ive tried using .pack instead of a grid then program just didnt even run then now ive tried making a frame and putting it into the frame and no luck

You put a frame with height 250 and the "Open Task Manager"  button in the same cell (row 1, column 0). Should the two buttons be put inside that frame instead?

Yeah i was trying to get the buttons into a frame so i could like set the width= but it wouldnt work

But currently the buttons are not put in that frame.

How so? Ive made the Frame and put it in my_tab2 shouldnt that mean anything in my_tab2 is in the frame?

Yes currently the frame with height 250 and the two buttons are put in the frame my_tab2.  I ask whether the two buttons are to be put into the frame with height 250?

Oh yea thats correct the two buttons go into the frame with height 250

If you want to put the two buttons into the frame with height 250, you need to set the parent option of the two buttons to that frame instead of my_tab2:
frame = Frame(my_tab2, width=250, height=250)
frame.grid()

Button(frame, text="Open Task Manager", command=taskmgr).pack()#grid(row=1, column=0)
Button(frame, text="Open Control Panel", command=ctrlpanel).pack()#grid(row=2, column=0)

